# Input submit border inside with set dimensions

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Please don't suggest I stop using `<input type="submit">` I need to support non javascript-enabled users.

I have a submit button, and on `:hover` I apply a border to it. However I have noticed that in Firefox 15 and IE7 the border gets applied to the inside of the element. This appears to be because I have set a fixed `width` and a `height` to the element and behaves normally once I remove them. However due to browser inconsistencies I need the width and height to ensure the submit button is the same size in all browsers.

[image: Submit button border bug]

Does anyone know how to prevent the border from being drawn inside the element?

Relevant CSS:

```
#searchform .submit {
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
    height: 31px;
    width: 31px;
    position: relative;
    left: -4px;
    margin-right: -4px;
    background-image: url(library/images/search-icon.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
#searchform .submit:hover {
    margin: -2px -6px 0px 0px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="" class="submit btn" />
```

Comment: Is it about using `border: 2px 2px 2px 0px` in `submit.hover` or I misunderstood the question

Comment: @Ankit Look at the image, the border is being drawn inside the element and not outside as a border should in Firefox 15 and IE7 (Probably other versions to).

Comment: As your submit button is an image anyway, I'd create an image sprite if I were you which you can change the background-position of on :hover. You can get a bit more control then by not using a CSS border at all. Cannot stand IE7 border rendering (amongst other things it also tries to do).

Comment: Is this behaviour also there when you remove margin change on Hover ?

Comment: @Ankit Yes that is just to put the button back in place on browsers which correctly render the border. The problem is directly related to the button having a fixed width and height.

Comment: @ScottBrown Possible but not as elegant of a solution as I'd hoped for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wonder if there is a `box-sizing` property being applied to this input. `box-sizing: border-box` would cause border & padding to occur within width and height. I wonder if you're using a CSS template that uses the `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` technique. Try

```
#searchform .submit { box-sizing: content-box; }
```

Comment: Hey smartypants... `-moz-box-sizing: content-box;` fixed it for Firefox so it seems your right. IE7 is still being naughty though (doesn't understand `box-sizing`) but I can handle that with a conditional CSS and increased width.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the margin when **hover** to the button?

```
#searchform .submit:hover {
border: 2px solid #000;
```

}

Comment: The margin is not the problem, that is for browsers that render the border correctly. With or without it the border renders inside.

Comment: i misunderstood the question :D

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use this:

```
border: 2px solid #3393B5;
```

Or:

```
border: 2px solid #fff;
```

Instead of:

```
border: 2px solid #000;
```